# Shading Issue on Sharp Cutting Edge of an Axe

Tags: modeling, materials, edges

I'm working on a model of an axe and I've run into a bit of a shading issue on the very sharp edge of the axe when it's viewed from certain angles.

Update: I added a picture of the face orientation. It seems like the inside normals are peeking through on the sharp edge of the axe, causing the issue. I can't seem to fix it by moving things around or recalculating normals.

I think the problem has to do with the metallic and low roughness material when it gets to the very sharp edge, but I can't seem to fix it while still maintaining the look that I'm after. Is there any way to get rid of the weird shading on the sharp edge but keep the material?

I'm pretty new to 3D modeling, so I really appreciate any help that you can give me.

[image]

[image: axe shading issue]

[image: edge flow]

[image: normals]

Comment: hello, maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots sorry about that, I have added a link to the blend file.

Comment: I'm not sure there's any technical problem, if you enlarge this face a bit it disappears

Comment: @moonboots thank you for your comment, but I was not able to fix it by making the face bigger. I added a picture showing the face orientation, which shows the inside normals are somehow peeking through on the sharp edge. I am not sure how to resolve that.